Obtaining the geodesic extension property by embedding in a larger space
Suppose $(X,d)$ is a Hadamard space. By considering basic examples like a compact interval in $\mathbb{R}$ or a closed unit ball in Hilbert space, $X$ need not have the geodesic extension property (geodesics defined on compact intervals cannot be extended into geodesic rays). I am wondering if it is always true that $X$ can be embedded isometrically into some larger Hadamard space with the geodesic extension property.

Yes, of course, just add infinite  "needles" to your space at every point.

Thank you this is a simple and elegant resolution. @MoisheKohan
